# Spring resolved property file location needs to resolve those properties

Tags: java, spring, properties, configuration, config

I am using Spring version 4.0.6.RELEASE and am trying to have spring read from a properties file and use one of the resolved properties to provide a location to another properties file.  My spring.xml file has the following:

```
    <bean id="applicationProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:application.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:version.properties</value>
            <!- The below file contains the another file location -->
            <value>file:${catalina.base}/conf/instance.properties</value>
            <value>${another.file.location}</value>

        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

instance.properties contains:

```
account.id=BlahBlahBlah
another.file.location=file:/Users/beardman/.myapp/local.properties
```

and /Users/beardman/.myapp/local.properties contains:

```
magic.number=3
database.endpoint=blah
```

I keep getting the following warning:

```
WARN  [main] o.s.b.f.c.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer Could not load properties from ServletContext resource [/${another.file.location}]: Could not open ServletContext resource [/${another.file.location}]
```

When debugging my code, I can see that the account.id was injected correctly, but I can never get the magic.number or database.endpoint to show up.  How can I get spring to use the resolved property from the instance.properties file as the value for the another.file.location?

EDIT:  Added property file contents

Comment: It look's like your path values are not set the right way or they don't exist

Comment: That's a good point @CodeFox, but I have verified that the files do exist in their proper locations and I actually get properties from instance.properties file, just nothing from my local.properties file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring by default replaces property placeholders with system properties.  Since you want to use properties defined in an external file as well, you need to create a [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer)
This tag is the shorthand, but you can define PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer as a bean if you need more control.  Add this before your applicationProperties bean

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:${catalina.base}/conf/instance.properties"/>
```

Note that properties in the file will override system properties in the default mode.  You can specify that system properties are checked first by adding the attribute `systemPropertiesMode="override"` to the `property-placeholder` element

Comment: Properties from the instance.properties file are read correctly, but I cannot get spring to translate the another.file.location property that is defined in instance.properties and actually read the properties in another.file.location.

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I tried the context:property-placeholder in multiple different configurations and the `another.file.location` is never resolved.

Comment: @beardman The warning for PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer is not for the portion of the config you posted, but for another bean trying to load ${another.file.location} as property placeholders.  You need to load instance.properties using a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer BEFORE you can use ${another.file.location} anywhere.  If you're also trying to load properties from ${another.file.location} to use as placeholders, you need to put it in a second PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer somewhere after the one with instance.properties.